# Cmake can't find Opencv4 dependencies using vcpkg

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, vcpkg

Steps to reproduce:

```
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
.\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
.\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe install opencv4 --triplet=x64-windows-static
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=.\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows-static .
cmake --build build --config Release
```

This command fails, saying:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\vcpkg\packages\opencv4_x64-windows-static\lib\jpeg.lib' [D:<myfolder>]
```

The linker  appears to be looking in the wrong directory for `jpeg.lib`, because this file does actually exist in

`.\vcpkg\packages\libjpeg-turbo_x64-windows-static\lib\`

My `CMakelists.txt file looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(Analysis)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/packages")

set(OpenCV_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/packages/opencv4_x64-windows-static/share/opencv4/")
set(TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/packages/tiff_x64-windows-static/include")
set(TIFF_LIBRARY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/packages/tiff_x64-windows-static/lib/tiff.lib")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(TIFF REQUIRED) 
... (set up executables)
```

How can I fix the linker here?

Comment: Don't setup `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and variables related to libraries. `find_package` is all you need

Comment: ok. I commented that out but still get the same error @Osyotr

Comment: Delete cache and reconfigure

Comment: OK. well that seemed to solve those errors, now I'm getting different ones. ` error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease'` but thank you I guess that was the problem.

Comment: It's because `x64-windows-static` uses static CRT (aka MT) and your project uses dynamic (aka MD). See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html

Comment: thanks this solved the build issues @Osyotr